# test-path on multiple PCs output coming out not how i want it

Tags: powershell

Test-path to my floor machines to make sure the destination is true and then after moving the file testing if the file exists. How can I get this to come out so the second half has true or false?

If i run them separate I get an output.

```
PS C:\Users\amandaw.QPC> Get-Content C:\apps\currentcomputers.txt | `
   Select-Object @{Name='ComputerName';Expression={$_}},@{Name='ItemExist';Expression={ Test-Path "\\$_\c$\apps\$file"}}

ComputerName ItemExist
------------ ---------
Commercial1       True
TC-15             True
Floor03           True
Floor04           True
Mixit-PC          True
TC2018B           True
FLOOR07           True
tc2017p           True
Floor09           True
TC2017k           True
tc2017g           True
ptc-6             True
tc2017a           True
tc2017b           True
Floor15           True
tc2019z           True
tc2019b           True
```

---

```
# path to Item to be copied
$item = "C:\Workstation\Pictures\pngtree___material_distribution_939546_1MJ_icon.ico"
#item
$file = "pngtree___material_distribution_939546_1MJ_icon.ico"


Get-Content C:\apps\currentcomputers.txt | `
   Select-Object @{Name='ComputerName';Expression={$_}},@{Name='PathExist';Expression={ Test-Path "\\$_\c$\apps"}}
```

(copy the files- left out since don't need help with that)

```
Get-Content C:\apps\currentcomputers.txt | `
   Select-Object @{Name='ComputerName';Expression={$_}},@{Name='ItemExist';Expression={ Test-Path "\\$_\c$\apps\$file"}}
```

Output...

```
PS C:\Users\amandaw.QPC> C:\Workstation\Documents\WindowsPowerShell.batch\Untitled5.ps1

ComputerName PathExist
------------ ---------
Commercial1       True
TC-15             True
Floor03           True
Floor04           True
Mixit-PC          True
TC2018B           True
FLOOR07           True
tc2017p           True
Floor09           True
TC2017k           True
tc2017g           True
ptc-6             True
tc2017a           True
tc2017b           True
Floor15           True
tc2019z           True
tc2019b           True
Commercial1           
TC-15                 
Floor03               
Floor04               
Mixit-PC              
TC2018B               
FLOOR07               
tc2017p               
Floor09               
TC2017k               
tc2017g               
ptc-6                 
tc2017a               
tc2017b               
Floor15               
tc2019z               
tc2019b
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I'd read in the computers as a csv file
  (supplying a header) and
- append the two new (empty) fields with a `Select-Object`.
- iterate the Object and populate the fields by using `Test-Path` with `-PathType`

```
## Q:\Test\2019\06\26\SO_56779528.ps1
# path to Item to be copied
$item = Get-Item "C:\Workstation\Pictures\pngtree___material_distribution_939546_1MJ_icon.ico"
#item
$file = $item.Name

$Computers = Import-Csv C:\apps\currentcomputers.txt -Header Name |
    Select-Object *,PathExist,ItemExist

ForEach($Computer in $Computers){
   $Computer.PathExist = (Test-Path "\\$($Computer.Name)\c`$\apps" -PathType Container)

   #(copy the files- left out since don't need help with that)

   $Computer.ItemExist = (Test-Path "\\$($Computer.Name)\c`$\apps\$file" -PathType Leaf)
}

$Computers
# $Computers | Out-GridView
# $Computers | Export-Csv C:\apps\Computers.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Simulated sample ouput:

```
> $Computers

Name         PathExists ItemExists
----         ---------- ----------
Commercial1        True       True
TC-15              True      False
Floor03           False      False
```

Comment: that works great! Thanks. I especially love the out-gridview. I'm new to powershell and haven't used it before. Only change i needed to make to get it to work was line 15 -PathType Leaf) instead of -PathType Leaf}

Comment: Sorry for he typo and thanks for feedback. Hint for a new contributor: If an answer solves your question or you find it helpful you should consider to [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)? and/or [vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) (once you've got a [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) of 15 it will be seen)